# Haskell: Run two monads, keep the result of the first one

Tags: haskell, monads

Playing with Haskell and now I try to create a function like

```
keepValue :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a
```

with following semantic: it should apply monad value to a function, which return the second monad, and *keep the **result** of the first monad, but the **effect** of the second one*

I have a working function in case of `Maybe` monad:

```
keepValueMaybe :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe a

keepValue ma f = case ma >>= f of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just _ -> ma
```

So if the first value is `Nothing`, the function is not run (so no second side-effect), but if the first value is `Just`, then, the function is run (with side effect). I keep **effect** of the second computation (e.g., `Nothing` makes the whole expression `Nothing`), but the original value.

Now I wonder. Can it work for any monad?

It looks kinda built-in `>>`, but I couldn't find anything in standard library.

Comment: In general, you can't do anything to 'throw away' the effect of a monadic action. If you actually want to keep both effects, then your function is `\x f -> x >>= \a -> f a >> return a`.

Comment: In the most general case, the *result* given by a monadic function depends on its *efect* (or its secret), so I don't think you can just avoid the efect of some chosen monadic function. (I'm thinking about IO... what if `m a` takes the `a` from the standard input?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's walk through this!

```
keepValue :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a
keepValue ma f = _
```

So what do we want `keepValue` to do?  Well, the first thing we should do is use `ma`, so we can connect it to `f`.

```
keepValue :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a
keepValue ma f = do
  a <- ma
  _
```

Now we have a value `va` of type `a`, so we can pass it to `f`.

```
keepValue :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a
keepValue ma f = do
  va <- ma
  vb <- f va
  _
```

And finally, we want to produce `va`, so we can just do that:

```
keepValue :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a
keepValue ma f = do
  va <- ma
  vb <- f va
  return va
```

This is how I'd walk through writing the first draft of any monadic function like this.  Then, I'd clean it up.  First, some small things: since `Applicative` is a superclass of `Monad`, I prefer `pure` to `return`; we didn't use `vb`; and I'd drop the `v` in the names.  So for a `do`-notation based version of this function, I think the best option is

```
keepValue :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a
keepValue ma f = do
  a <- ma
  _ <- f a
  pure a
```

Now, however, we can start to make the implementation better.  First, we can replace `_ <- f va` with an explicit call to `(>>)`:

```
keepValue :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a
keepValue ma f = do
  a <- ma
  f a >> pure a
```

And now, we can apply a simplification.  You may know that we can always replace `(>>=)` plus `pure`/`return` with `fmap`/`(<$>)`: any of `pure . f =<< ma`, `ma >>= pure . f`, or `do a <- ma ; pure $ f a` (all of which are equivalent) can be replaced by `f <$> ma`.  However, the `Functor` type class has another, less-well-known method, [`(<$)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36-):

> `(<$) :: a -> f b -> f a`
>   Replace all locations in the input with the same value. The default definition is `fmap . const`, but this may be overridden with a more efficient version.

So we have a similar replacement rule for `(<$)`: we can always replace `ma >> pure b` or `do ma ; pure b` with `b <$ ma`.  This gives us

```
keepValue :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a
keepValue ma f = do
  a <- ma
  a <$ f a
```

And I think this is the shortest reasonable version of this function!  There aren't any nice point-free tricks to make this cleaner; one indicator of that is the multiple use of `a` on the second line of the `do` block.

---

Incidentally, a terminology note: you're running two *monadic actions*, or two *monadic values*; you're not running *"two monads".  A monad is something like `Maybe` – a type constructor which supports `(>>=)` and `return`.  Don't mix the values up with the types – this sort of terminological distinction helps keep things clearer!

Comment: You mean `import Control.Arrow; keepValue ma f = ma >>= uncurry (>>) . (f &&& return)` doesn't count as a nice trick? ;-P

Comment: @ephemient: I prefer `(. ((<$) <*>)) . (>>=)`, personally :-)  Or `ma >>= (<$) <*> f`, if you really like variable names!

Comment: These are the times when even perl coders get pale with envy of us haskellers, because when our cats walk over the keyboard it is type checked

Answer (score 1):

This structure looks a lot like the definition of `>>=`/`>>` for `Monad Maybe`.

```
case foo of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just _ -> bar

foo >>= \_ -> bar
foo >> bar
```

so your original expression could be simplified to

```
ma >>= f >> ma
```

and this works for other monads.

However, I don't think this is actually what you want, as you can see `ma` occurring twice. Instead, take the value from the first `ma >>=` bind, and carry it through to the end of the computation.

```
keepValue ma f =
    ma >>= \a ->
    f a >>
    return a
```

or in `do`-notation

```
keepValue ma f = do
    a <- ma
    f a
    return a
```

Comment: An example of why you don't want `ma >>= f >> ma`: that does something very different in `IO` when `ma` is something like `spendMoney`! :-)  Or more prosaically: `getLine >>= print >> getLine` reads in two lines, `keepValue getLine print` reads in only one.

Answer (score 1):

You could define:

```
passThrough f = (>>) <$> f <*> pure
```

and then inplace of

```
keepValue ma f
```

write

```
ma >>= passThrough f
```

Then to read a line and print it twice (say) would be

```
getLine >>= passThrough putStrLn >>= putStrLn
```